# Quarkus CDI: lookup and startup event

Tags: java, quarkus, cdi

Starting from the code in the official [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#declaratively-choose-beans-that-can-be-obtained-by-programmatic-lookup), I have created the following structure:

```
interface Service {
  String name();
}

@LookupIfProperty(name = "service.foo.enabled", stringValue = "true")
@ApplicationScoped
class ServiceFoo implements Service {

  public String name() {
    return "foo";
  }
}

@ApplicationScoped
class ServiceBar implements Service {

  @Startup
  public void onStart() { // startup logic }

  public String name() {
    return "bar";
  }
}
```

The code in ServiceBar.onStart() gets always executed even if the bean does not get injected. Is there a way to execute the ServiceBar startup logic only when ServiceFoo is disabled?

Comment: `@LookupIfProperty` only affects the ability to obtain the bean using programmatic lookup. It doesn't affect enablement in any way. Both `ServiceFoo` and `ServiceBar` are enabled in this case, and hence the startup method must be called. And in case you ask, no, there is no way in Quarkus to enable/disable a bean based on a condition evaluated at runtime. Enablement is solely determined during application build.

Answer (score 0):

As already described by @ladicek, `LookupIfProperty` does not affect enablement. As a workaround, I have changed the code in the following way:

```
interface Service {
  String name();
}

@LookupIfProperty(name = "service.foo.enabled", stringValue = "true")
@ApplicationScoped
class ServiceFoo implements Service {

  public String name() {
    return "foo";
  }
}

@ApplicationScoped
class ServiceBar implements Service {

  @ConfigProperty(name = "service.foo.enabled", defaultValue = "false")
  Boolean isFooEnabled;

  @Startup
  public void onStart() { 
    if (!isFooEnabled) {
      // startup logic
    }
  }

  public String name() {
    return "bar";
  }
}
```

In this way, the startup logic gets executed only when ServiceFoo is not enabled. Is not super elegant, but it works.